# python request.get is not working while curl does work

Tags: python, python-requests

I can basically do the following in bash: (works fine)

```
$COOKIE=mycookies
curl -b $COOKIE http://localhost:8080/data
```

but not in python (I followed: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/),

```
cookies = dict(cookies_are='mycookies')
response = requests.get(url='http://localhost:8080/data', 
                        cookies=cookies)
print response.status_code
print response.text
```

I keep getting

```
<li><a href="#">Unauthenticated</a></li>
```

Comment: Could you please post the exact code you are running? Your python example doesn't even have a closing quote.

Comment: sorry when I copy pasted this i deleted a quote

Comment: it's exactly what I have posted now, sorry I messed up copy/pasting

Answer (score 0):

So... it might seem silly, and I can't tell if this is just an error in how you posted the question or not, but it would seem that you are messing up the dictionary and using the wrong version.

```
cookies = dict(cookies_are='mycookies')
```

should be more like

```
cookies = os.environ['COOKIE']
cookies = json.dumps(mycookies)
```

Comment: what does cookies = os.environ['COOKIE'] do? because I get a key error

Comment: Ah, that's checking for an environment variable called COOKIE. I just used that example because that's what you were setting the variable equal to in your example. That should just be whatever your cookie dictionary is.